# how to import android.os.bundle format in normal java projects?

Tags: java, android, sockets

I am trying to send data in android.os.bundle format from an Android Emulator to a PC server through socket. Now I could get the object from ObjectInputStream on the PC server end, but I couldn't convert it into the bundle format.

here are some key lines of my code on the PC server end:

```
android.os.Bundle testInfo = new android.os.Bundle();
ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(client.getInputStream());
testInfo = (Bundle)in.readObject();
```

And this is what the console demonstrates:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!
at android.os.Bundle.<init>(Bundle.java:5)
at TCPDesktopServer.run(TCPDesktopServer.java:31)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: I don't think you can easily use the Android classes in "normal" Java SE. As the exception indicates the classes you are using right now are stubs and don't contain the real implementation. The real implementation is part of Android and probably not trivially ported to full Java.

Comment: You should store your data in Serializable instead. `ObjectOutputStream` is available across all possible Java platforms and versions. It was designed specifically for things like network data transfer. But it does not support Parcelables, only `Searializable` objects

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can do this so easily.

But even if you can succeed in using android.os.Bundle in your server you really shouldn't, because you will get stuck in an Android format that can change eventually.

Besides of being an Android app it is really a matter of decoupling your solution. And you can do that using a neutral format to transfer data through your socket connection. That way a change in Android API won't necessarily result in a change in your PC Server implementation.

I would recommend you to use a format like XML, JSON or YAML.

That way you will probably have to make a translator from android.os.Bundle to the neutral format of your choice in your Android app but you will have the benefit of decoupling your solution.

Another benefit is that if tomorrow you need to connect a new application with your server you won't have to deal with Android API in the new application.